# check string if it valid javascript in the browser

Tags: javascript, browser

let's assume i got some string from `window.postMessage` and I want to know if it valid JS without execute it .
how can I do that ?

like what we have for DOM:

```js
var domparser = new DOMParser();​​​​​​
var doc = domparser.parseFromString(string, 'text/html')
```

`eval` is not good because it run the code.

`Function` just return `function` with the `string` in the function's body

Comment: You could maybe use a Linter, this should check for valid Javascript in a syntax way.

Comment: linter in the browser run time?

Comment: Yes, you can get browser based linters..  EsLint for example can be used in browser, here is a demo running browser.  https://eslint.org/demo

Comment: Ok, it good direction. but need Remove completely all the "linter" so it just tell me if it valid JS

Comment: Yes, I believe if you remove all the options it's going to just check if it's valid.  Another option if your only interested in been valid is use the first part of a Linter, and that's the AST compiler.   There are lots of options here, try -> https://astexplorer.net/